# In SQL Trigger check if an Insert contains a value for a column

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I do have a trigger in my SQL table and I'm trying to check whether or not an insert contains a value for column `Produktnummer`. My reasoning behind this is whether or not to run another insert which would be caused by the trigger.

I do have this inside my trigger before the actual insert my trigger would cause.
`IF NEW.Produktnummer IS NOT NULL OR NOT '' THEN` followed by `END IF` at the end.

My trigger looks like this:

```
IF NEW.Produktnummer IS NOT NULL OR NOT '' THEN
[This piece triggers another Insert]
END IF
```

But It seems like the if expression is always true even when my insert didn't even contain a value for `NEW.Produktnummer`.

Can I even check for `IS NOT NULL OR NOT ''` with NEW variables inside triggers or is there another way to conditionally run the statement inside the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`''` is a false-y in a boolean context, so `NOT ''` is true, and the `if` condition is always true. It looks like you meant to check `Produktnummer` with a `<>` operator:

```
IF NEW.Produktnummer IS NOT NULL AND NEW.Produktnummer <> '' THEN
    -- trigger the other insert
END IF
```